# PHP показать информацию после того как вошли в систему

Tags: php, html, sql

У меня такой вопрос я создал форму для регистрации и потом чтобы войти. Так вот для регистрации надо вводить почту пароль телефон и Фамилию.  Вот код:

```
<?php
include_once('dbcon.php');

$error = false;
if(isset($_POST['buttonreg'])){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $name = strip_tags($name);
    $name = htmlspecialchars($name);

    $tel = $_POST['tel'];
    $tel = strip_tags($tel);
    $tel = htmlspecialchars($tel);

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $email = strip_tags($email);
    $email = htmlspecialchars($email);

    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $password = strip_tags($password);
    $password = htmlspecialchars($password);
      //encrypt password with md5
    $password = md5($password);

    //insert data if no error
    if(!$error){
        $sql = "insert into users(name,tel, email ,password)
        values('$name','$tel', '$email', '$password')";
        if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
            header('location: index.php');

        }else{
            echo 'Error '.mysqli_error($conn);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

А войти можно с помощью почты и пароля:

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once('dbcon.php');

$error = false;
if(isset($_POST['buttonlogin'])){
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    $email = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($email));

    $password = trim($_POST['password']);
    $password = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($password));



    if(!$error){
        $password = md5($password);
        $sql = "select * from users where email='$email' ";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        if($count==1 && $row['password'] == $password){
            $_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];
            header('location: home.php');
        }else{
            $errorMsg = '<center><p>Doğru olmayan email/şifrə daxil etmisiniz</p></center>';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Я хочу чтобы после того как зашел кто то там отображалась Имя Фамилия там телефон например т.д помогите мне буду блогадарен!

Comment: Что в файле `home.php` находится?

Comment: Та же страница только есть команда echo $_SESSION['email'] Как бы здраствуйте и та почта когда вошел с помощью кто то

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше было бы если показали пример кода `home.php`, а так можете вместо вывода вашего попробовать сделать выборку с базы по `email` который у вас в сессии и взять информацию с базы по нему и вывести всё что надо, к примеру вот так:

```
$sql = 'select * from users where email="'.$_SESSION['email'].'"';
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

echo 'Здраствуйте '. $user['name'] .'. Ваш телефон '. $user['name'] .', ваша почта: '.$user['email'];
```

Только учтите что это не безопасный подход, мы напрямую вставляем данные в sql запрос, их нужно фильтровать.

Comment: Блогадарю вас! попробую это и отвечу вам!

Comment: Вы мне очень помогли блогадарю нету слов! Чем я могу быть полезен для вас? Просто скажите